# Where's the particle system file in SceneKit in Xcode 11.3.1

Tags: swift, xcode, scenekit, virtual-reality

Recently I updated my Xcode to 11.3.1. But while working with `SceneKit`, I found that I can't create a particle system file.

- Before

[image: Before]

- After

[image: After]

How can I create a particle system in a file now?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### SceneKit Library

In Xcode 14 / 13 / 12 / 11 you have no preconfigured **`.scnp` particle system** files anymore. Instead, you can use a `Particle System` object coming from a Xcode Library (with the same settings in Attributes Inspector as they were in Xcode 10).

[image]

If you manually placed a `Particle System` from library into SceneKit's `Scene graph` you can then retrieve it and setup programmatically. Let's see how it looks like:

```
let particlesNode = sceneView.scene?.rootNode.childNode(withName: "particles", 
                                                     recursively: true)

particlesNode?.particleSystems?.first?.isAffectedByGravity = true
particlesNode?.particleSystems?.first?.acceleration.z = 5.0
```

### Creating particles programmatically

Or you can easily create a Particle System from scratch using just code:

```
let particleSystem = SCNParticleSystem()
    
particleSystem.birthRate = 1000
particleSystem.particleSize = 1.45
particleSystem.particleLifeSpan = 2
particleSystem.particleColor = .yellow

let particlesNode = SCNNode()
particlesNode.addParticleSystem(particleSystem)

sceneView.scene!.rootNode.addChildNode(particlesNode)
```

### Creating `.scnz` file containing Particle System

- Select a `.scn` file in Project Navigator (left pane) and choose File – Export...
- In drop-down menu choose **Compressed Scenekit Scene Document `.scnz`**

[image]

Or you can create `.scnp` file by renaming `.scn` – the same way @ycao proposed.

Answer (score 6):

Particle System moved to Scene Kit Scene File as a library object:

[image: Particle System in Library]

Comment: But I want to create a `Particle System (.scnp)` file.

Answer (score 2):

While creating a new file, select `SceneKit SceneFile`. Edit the suffix to `.scnp`, and everything is OK.

Answer (score -1):

You can also right click inside the scene graph viewport Create > ParticleSystem then adjust the settings as per usual in the properties inspector. Then do the usual stuff as mentioned above in code to retrieve the system, move about, change settings etc.